# Apache Rewrite Condition for Query String

Tags: apache, xss, query-string

I think someone trying to put some load on my website or hack, which I would like to stop. If you see below url there is a text as "<svg/class="elliot"onLoad=alert(document.domain)>" so my aim is to block if there's such query string appended.

xyz.com/nz?uid=56095fdd427-f35b-baedfdfdfd4-8bfdf22f2bc417f"><svg/class="elliot"onLoad=alert(document.domain)>

This appears to be some kind of Cross Site Scripting(XSS). But I already have blocked XSS attack with 'Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"' in my apache configuration. I'm not exactly sure whether this attack falls under XSS but this config is not working.

I have tried few ways before raising this request but it didn't help.
Could you help me here?

Thank you

Comment: *"But I already have blocked XSS attack with `'Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"`"* - this header only works on [browsers that respect it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection#browser_compatibility).

Comment: `xyz.com/nz?uid=56095fdd427-f35b-baedfdfdfd4-8bfdf22f2bc417f"><svg/class="elliot"onLoad=alert(document.domain)>` - please take a cup of coffee, sit down, and think: is that payload (the `<svg class="elliot" onLoad=alert(document.domain)>`) actually causes your app to spew an alert in browser? there are (in the wilds) tools to automate cross site scripting tests. they would send requests like that and see if your site: 1) actually reflects the payload somewhere in the html; 2) the alert executed. if neither happens, your site should be alright.